# BluetoothAdpater not removing the turned off bluetooth while scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Working on a use case where all the nearby bluetooth devices has to be scanned and listed in app, it is done using [BluetoothAapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html). It has an Action to get the newly detected device that can be added to the existing list, but after a device is being listed, it went off, 
I do not want to startDiscovery() again, how could I detect the device that turned off bluetooth and remove from the existing list. Please help me to have it solved

Comment: Proper way is to startDiscovery() once in the while and I think it is the only right way to do it. Why you don't wont discovering for devices again?

Comment: Yes, Good option.! Even I thought of it, but here the device would be scanning 24x7, If I do startDiscovery every now and then, it will drain the battery very soon, thats why looking for an alternative

Comment: Good question, provide what you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting

Comment: Followed a sample from https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-BluetoothScannerFinishedProject,  and delved further into how it works, basically the BTAdapter gives the developer an option to get the newly detected device, but not giving any option to find out already detected bluetooth going turned off, it is capable of detecting in its next discovery, didn't say I got error or something unexpected. In a nutshell,  "BluetoothADapter doesn't gives the device info that goes turned off or out of range"